# I am using a cell value in Excel to look up an array based on that cell value

Tags: excel, range, vlookup, named-ranges, vba

I am using =VLOOKUP(C$2;INDIRECT(C$2);6;FALSE)

One of the inputs (a serial number) is MK05391. When I create the range for this row and name it the same as the serial number it won't let me. Says that The name either does not start with letter/underscore, or there's something else namned the same thing. All other ranges can be named to correspond to the actual serial number (what the user will input in C2).

I cannot find anything named MK05391. When I press Ctrl+F3 I clearly see all ranges there, but cannot see an MK05391. Which other types of 'objects' that have accidentally been named MK05391 can hinder the range from being named just that?

I can provide the Excel worksheet if anybody can tell me how I can upload it here.

Any help is much appreciated. This is the last thing that I need to fix before it's finished. Well almost the last thing.. so any help is much appreciated!

Thanks!

Sincerely,
V

EDIT:

I just discovered what it does. The problem is when I try to name it MK05391 it goes to cell MK,5391. How can I either remove that cell or prevent excel from not letting me name a range after a cell value that is not even used?

Comment: `MK05391` is a viable cell reference and as such can not be used as a name for a named range.

Comment: Yeah. Just noticed that. But is there a way to bypass this? Because the range needs to be named after the instrument serial number (ie MK05391)?

Comment: You can't do either.  You will need to name it something like `nameMK05391` and use `INDIRECT("name" & C$2)`  then the user can put `MK05391` in the cell and it will find the correct range.

Comment: You, good sir, are a friggin' genious! Thanks so much for the help. It took me almost an hour to figure out that it was referring to a cell. Thanks for the help. Can I just ask what exactly does the " " and & do in this case?

Comment: The `&` is concatenates `"name"` and what is in C2.  So if C2 had `MK05391` then it concatenates to `nameMK05391` and it is that reference the INDIRECT returns to the VLOOKUP.